# "You get the picture"

Tags: словоупотребление, идиомы

The literal translation that is found to be most closely equivalent to the English meaning of this is

> *Вы по**Л**учите картину*,

but I don’t know if that is just the literal meaning of saying ‘someone is receiving a picture’ or the phrasal meaning in English.

‘You get the picture’ in English is a way of saying that ‘you get the idea’ of something.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I sometimes hear my girlfriend say "Улавливаешь мысль?" or "Улавливаешь?".

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens, Yes, it is a good variant of the interrogative form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have to type in 30 characters before I can write

> Ну ты понял

Comment: I just see this as , well you understand

Comment: @Almonds812: yes, this is what it means literally.

Comment: this is rare case when it's justified - it's that short yet not a comment but a self-sufficient answer )

Comment: This matches the meaning, but more colloquial, especially if "You get the picture" is part of a sentence.